# Python Selenium Extract all text between two spots

Tags: python, selenium

```
<a class="AAA" fid="41553" href="..">AAA</a></TD><td bgcolor = eeeeee><div align="center">
<a class="AAA" fid="43455" href="..">BBB</a></TD><td bgcolor = eeeeee><div align="center">
<a href="ctop.php?vdate=20220123"><font size=1>
01-23</div>
</a></td><td bgcolor = eeeeee><div align="center">abc</div></td><td bgcolor = eeeeee>
<div align="left">...</div></td><td bgcolor = eeeeee><font size=1>1200</td><td bgcolor = eeeeee>
<div align="left">...</div></td>
<td bgcolor = eeeeee><div align="center">....G1</div></td bgcolor = eeeeee><td  bgcolor = eeeeee><div align="left">  <font size=1>109<font color=blue><i>+3</i></font></td>
<td bgcolor = eeeeee><div align="center"><font size=1> 126</div></td><td bgcolor = eeeeee>
<div align="center"> <font size=1>1230</div></td><td bgcolor = eeeeee>
<div align="left">           <br><font color=red></div></td><td bgcolor = eeeeee><div align="center">....</div>
<a class="AAA" fid="47878" href="..">CCC</a></TD><td bgcolor = eeeeee><div align="center">
<a class="AAA" fid="47892" href="..">DDD</a></TD><td bgcolor = eeeeee><div align="center">
```

Lets say I want to navigate two spots by the start and end of the class 'AAA'. And after that I want to extract all the text in between. Can I use a if else condition on Selenium?

Comment: If you want to get all the text in all of the `<a>` tags with class `"AAA"`, that's easy.  There is no other text in that snippet.  You don't usually think about "in between" with Selenium.

Comment: Sorry, I have to reformat my equestion. There are other tags existed between two 'AAA' classes.

Comment: @What text do you want? There are multiple of them here.

Comment: Yes. What I mean is there any one-off methods to capture all the texts in between or I just need to looking into all the tags and capture them with different attributes step by step?

Comment: You can probably just find that element and apply `.text` on it. That'll get you all the text inside that web element.